# AWS OpsWorks S3 403 RestClient::Forbidden

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chef-infra, aws-opsworks

I am new with using Chef. I did create a very simple cookbook as zip file to S3 but I get this error always

```
[2015-12-07T10:29:53+00:00] INFO: Not needed with Chef 11.x (x >= 8) anymore.
[2015-12-07T10:29:53+00:00] INFO: Processing package[git] action install (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 21)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing package[perl-Digest-HMAC] action install (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 22)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing package[unzip] action install (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 24)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing template[/root/.s3curl] action create (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 24)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: template[/root/.s3curl] created file /root/.s3curl
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: template[/root/.s3curl] updated file contents /root/.s3curl
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: template[/root/.s3curl] mode changed to 600
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing directory[/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6] action create (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 32)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: directory[/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6] mode changed to 755
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing s3_file[/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6/archive] action create (opsworks_custom_cookbooks::checkout line 38)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] INFO: Processing chef_gem[rest-client] action install (s3_file::dependencies line 1)
[2015-12-07T10:29:54+00:00] WARN: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd47315478 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-1b2rwtr>, @code=403>
[2015-12-07T10:29:59+00:00] WARN: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd474094d8 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-pvv1v>, @code=403>
[2015-12-07T10:30:04+00:00] WARN: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd474b7268 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-5e98l1>, @code=403>
[2015-12-07T10:30:09+00:00] WARN: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd481acf18 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-10607v8>, @code=403>
[2015-12-07T10:30:14+00:00] WARN: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd48279f90 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-1659itz>, @code=403>
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] FATAL: #<RestClient::RawResponse:0x0055dd48300658 @net_http_res=#<Net::HTTPForbidden 403 Forbidden readbody=true>, @args={:method=>"GET", :url=>"https://jb-chef-cookbook.s3.amazonaws.com/cookbooks+3.zip", :raw_response=>true}, @file=#<Tempfile:/tmp/rest-client20151207-2439-1y4w8iq>, @code=403>

================================================================================
Error executing action `create` on resource 's3_file[/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6/archive]'
================================================================================


RestClient::Forbidden
---------------------
403 Forbidden


Cookbook Trace:
---------------
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:101:in `block in do_request'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:83:in `rescue in with_region_detect'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:78:in `with_region_detect'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:92:in `do_request'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:124:in `block in get_from_s3'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:122:in `each'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/libraries/s3_file.rb:122:in `get_from_s3'
/var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/s3_file/providers/default.rb:65:in `block in class_from_file'


Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/scm_helper/libraries/s3.rb

38:         s3_file "#{tmpdir}/archive" do
39:           bucket s3_bucket
40:           remote_path s3_key
41:           aws_access_key_id scm_options[:user]
42:           aws_secret_access_key scm_options[:password]
43:           owner "root"
44:           group "root"
45:           mode "0600"
46:           # per default it's host-style addressing
47:           # but older versions of rest-client doesn't support host-style addressing with `_` in bucket name
48:           s3_url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/#{s3_bucket}" if s3_bucket.include?("_")
49:           action :create
50:         end
51: 
52:         execute 'extract files' do
53:           command "#{node[:opsworks_agent][:current_dir]}/bin/extract #{tmpdir}/archive"
54:         end
55: 
56:         execute 'create git repository' do
57:           cwd "#{tmpdir}/archive.d"
58:           command "find . -type d -name .git -exec rm -rf {} \\;; find . -type f -name .gitignore -exec rm -f {} \\;; git init; git add .; git config user.name 'AWS OpsWorks'; git config user.email 'root@localhost'; git commit -m 'Create temporary repository from downloaded contents.'"
59:         end
60: 
61:         "#{tmpdir}/archive.d"
62:       end
63:     end
64:   end



Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/cookbooks/scm_helper/libraries/s3.rb:38:in `prepare_s3_checkouts'

s3_file("/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6/archive") do
action [:create]
retries 0
retry_delay 2
cookbook_name "opsworks_custom_cookbooks"
recipe_name "checkout"
bucket "jb-chef-cookbook"
remote_path "cookbooks+3.zip"
owner "root"
group "root"
mode "0600"
path "/tmp/opsworks20151207-2439-1lgn8x6/archive"
end



[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage1/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] ERROR: 403 Forbidden
[2015-12-07T10:30:19+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

[image: here is my .zip file]

What is missing ?! any advices ? thanks

Comment: I'm guessing this is an S3 permissions problem, or a credentials problem.

Answer (score 2):

The S3 file you are trying to access doesn't have permissions set up correctly.

Comment: The S3 bucket has Open/download rights for every one ! as well as the .zip file.

Comment: Either you are incorrect on the ACLs or you are providing it invalid credentials. Pick one.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks it was my ACLs. I fixed it and now i had different problem !

[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 404 Not Found: Object not found: /reports/nodes/c2.localdomain/runs
[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] INFO: HTTP Request Returned 412 Precondition Failed: No such cookbook: docker

### Missing Cookbooks:

No such cookbook: docker

[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/lib/aws/opsworks/cache.stage2/chef-stacktrace.out
[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] ERROR: 412 "Precondition Failed"
[2015-12-08T13:07:18+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)